# Input SELECT right side Pull Down button missing

Tags: html, css, select

I am using Bootstrap 3 & custom styles from internet. 
But `Select drop down` right side `pull down` button is missing in all select boxes.

Can some body provide me the CSS to get it back?

```
<select name="test" id="test1" class="form-control">
    <option selected value="NONE">No Idea</option>
    <option value="PRIVATE">PRIVATE</option>
    <option value="PUBLIC">PUBLIC</option>
</select>
```

[image]

CSS from Inspect Element
[image]

This is How I fixed.

I added following two div before the `form` with `form-horizontal` class

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <select name="test" id="test1" class="form-control">
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the HTML (even if you strip it down and put in a few generic options) and the custom CSS?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks abdul.  Another question...does it do this in all browsers?

Comment: After looking around, it seems a few have had this problem.  It is either browser related, or the element containing the select is hiding the dropdown arrow.

Comment: Exactly. In chrome it is showing, In Firefox nothing.

Comment: Thanks every one. I added the solution to the problem. May be it helps other.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the `show-menu-arrow` class to your select element?

```
<select name="test" id="test1" class="form-control show-menu-arrow">
    <option selected value="NONE">No Idea</option>
    <option value="PRIVATE">PRIVATE</option>
    <option value="PUBLIC">PUBLIC</option>
</select>
```

As seen from here: http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

UPDATE:

It looks like bootstrap convention is to use a `ul` element to achieve a styled drop down instead of the `select` element. However, you could also try adding this in your select: `<span class="caret"></span>`

Comment: thanks for the two suggestions. But it is not working.